# How to use or operator in a view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view page and I want to show two content type same time. What I want is simple: I have two content types and these content types have own type fields. Like this:

Content Type 1 - Cars (this have a type field names "BMW")

Content Type 2 - Motorcycle (this have a type field names "Ducati")

I want to show all BMW Cars and Ducati Motorcycles at the same page. How can I do that with view filters? I try that but it is not working:

[image]

In my example;

Cars = Post

Motorcycle = Feed

BMW = Type (= iframe)

Ducati = Type (or foto, video, ...)

Comment: i don't get why you used foto, video or iframe as content type in the view when you only need Feed and Post content type content.

Comment: I dont want to show all contents in Feed and Post. Actually I need two filter: One for Post and one for Feed bevause these two has own type fields. And combine together in a one view.

Comment: Like this: I want to show all BMW Cars and Ducati Motorcycles at the same page... Cars = Post / Motorcycle = Feed / BMW = Type (= iframe) / Ducati = Type (or foto, video, ...)

Comment: Do you have two content types or more than five? Or is your screenshot weird because the taxonomy field is called "Type"?

Answer (score 0):

Only two filters can do that for you -

- Content : Published(= yes)

**OR,**

- Content : type(= Feed) **And,**
- Content : field_car(= BMW)

**OR,**

- Content : type(= Post) **And,**
- Content : field_motorcycle(= DUCATI)

Apply pager for the view with 10 or 15 content on one page, etc.

Comment: I dont want to show all contents in Feed and Post.

Comment: Actually I need two filter: One for Post and one for Feed because these two has own type fields. And combine together in a one view.

Comment: You edited your answer I did not see it sorry.. I try that but it is not working. http://i63.tinypic.com/21271ht.jpg